# iOS in app purchases - "Invalid product ID"

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

So I think I did all the steps to try to put in-app purchases onto my app, but it still just says "Invalid product ID".

1. I made the app on Xcode
2. I registered a bundle ID on xcode
3. I went to developer.apple.com and checked that the App ID is there, and it is.
4. I signed into itunes connect and created a new app. I used the same bundle ID.
5. I created an in-app purchase and created a product id for that (it says ready to submit).
6. I followed a tutorial and used SwiftyStoreKit (installed with cocoapods) to put in-app purchases on my app, and used the same product ID I created a step ago.
7. I delete the app on my phone, and then build it onto the phone again.
8. I test it, and it says invalid product ID.

the log of the error:`error(__C.SKError(_nsError: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=3 "Invalid product id: NWPremium" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid product id: NWPremium}))`

Do I have to submit the app for review before in-app purchases will work or something? Because the tutorial I followed didn't have to do that. Did I go wrong by registering the bundle ID in xcode first?

Comment: did u added ur user id? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: You mean test user? Yes, I created a test user. However, the pop-up to purchase never even appears in the first place.

Comment: can u share your logs as well?

Comment: @AmodGokhale edited to include log

Comment: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/issues/154 review the comment given by bizz84 on Mar 22. Thread contains detail note given by apple. Make sure all of them are fulfilled. I tested with a test program and its working correctly. 1. If app is production make sure in-app purchase is ready for sale 2. If app in sandbox .. provision profile issue. 3. Paid agreement license not accepted in itunes. I assume in your case point 2 & 3 might be an issue